# Dynamically create version in Carrierwave with Polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a polymorphic relationship set up with Carrierwave.

I want to create different versions of the images based on their model. So each model will have the sizes declared and Carrierwave will use them to process the images. [This article](http://andreapavoni.com/blog/2012/3/using-one-carrierwave-image-uploader-with-different-sizes-on-several-models/) has explained how to do it nicely.

I want to get `model.imageable` in my uploader to get the `IMAGE_SIZES` array of the particular model, before the versions of the images are created.

Currently, I get the following error:
`uninitialized constant NilClass::IMAGE_SIZES`
on this ilne: `resize_to_fit *(model.imageable.class::IMAGE_SIZES[size])`

How do I get `model.imageable` in the uploader. Is there any better way to achieve this while using polymorphic relationship?

`app/models/image.rb`

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :picture, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

`app/models/article.rb`

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

  IMAGE_SIZES = {
    thumb: [132, 132]
  }
end
```

`app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb`

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  process dynamic_resize_to_fit: :default

  version :thumb do
    process dynamic_resize_to_fit: :thumb
  end

  def dynamic_resize_to_fit(size)
    resize_to_fit *(model.imageable.class::IMAGE_SIZES[size])
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    return false if method.to_s.match(/has_(.*)_size\?/)
  end

  def setup_available_sizes
    model.imageable.class::IMAGE_SIZES.keys.each do |key|
      self.class_eval do
        define_method("has_#{key}_size?".to_sym) { true }
      end
    end
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Try to use `inverse_of` option. You can read about [here](https://www.viget.com/articles/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations)

Comment: `inverse_of` doesn't work on polymorphic relations. Does it?

Comment: it's likely you are right